# Chartboost not showing adds in iPad

Tags: ios

I am using chart boost for the first time. I included the code in my App . I then registered my application on chart boost and got a `appId` and `appSignature`. I did NOT provide `iTunesId` , `iTunesURL`,`View Callbacl URL`,`Click CallbackURL`,`InstallCallBackURL` while registering. I started a publishing and a advertising campaign. I added my device to those campaigns. Campaigns are showing active. 
But I get a message `failure to load Interstitial Adds` with my own `appId` and `appSignature`. But I see the adds if I use  `appId` and `appSignature` used in sample code provided by chartboost (here https://github.com/ChartBoost/client-examples). Am I missing something?. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I just had to wait a little bit longer to get the adds about more than an hour and adds started coming up on there own. Imp step was to start a publishing campaign.

Comment: I haven't started any campaign but ads are being shown on simulator but not coming on device. Any solution for this problem?

Comment: @LegendReborn : have you added your device as test device on chart boost ?